# Can't access Tor authcookie file from third party program

Tags: relays, configuration, linux, ubuntu

I've been trying for hours to get a munin monitoring plugin to hook into the Tor control port without success.  The problem is that it's unable to access the Tor authcookie in /var/run/tor with the error permission denied.  I've tried everything: Running the script as root, adding both root and www-data (it's a php script) into the debain-tor usergroup, changing permissions on /var/run/tor and /var/run/tor/control.authcokie (which works, but then prevents Tor from starting up throwing an error saying that the permissions aren't tight enough >.>), even changing the location of where Tor saves the cookie file all without success.

I've set the setting CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1 in torrc and restarted Tor and the monitoring tool more times than I can count, all without luck.  Is there some way to allow programs to access the cookie file while still maintaining strict enough permissions to allow Tor to start and run successfully?

Comment: I had to join the debian-tor group and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head (I haven't thought about the security implications in any detail) I would:

- Set `CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1`
- Start Tor
- Figure out exactly what group Tor's process is running with (I'm not sure on Ubuntu) by running `ps -aeo "%U %G %c" | grep tor` (group is in the second column)
- Unless group is `root` (in which case I wouldn't follow this advice), have your munin plugin run with said group by following [these instructions](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/faq#Q:CanImakethepluginrunasanotherusergroupthannobodynogroup), designed for exactly this purpose.

Done.

Comment: The ps command gave this: debian-+ debian-+ tor

I tried debain, debian-, and debian-+ and all gave a group doesn't exist error for munin.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Without more information it's hard to say.  Have you considered using password auth on the control port?

Comment: Yeah I think that may be the best option at this point.  The only problem is that the plugin was written without making changes to the code myself.  But hey - it may be a fun challenge!

EDIT: Thanks so much for your help; can't thank you enough!